# Override the implementation of a function inside the shared library but not directly invoked in our program

Tags: c++, linux, linker, shared-libraries, ldd

In C++, is that possible to change the behavior of a global function that is inside (not isolated from) one shared library but not directly invoked by the program? The program is dynamically loading the shared library and use the function by [dlopen](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and [dlsym](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlsym) at runtime.

For example, the functions `foo()` and `bar()` are both implemented in `libX.so`, `bar()` will call `foo()`, the program will only invoke `bar()`. Can the implementation of `foo()` be changed? Assume the we know the manglename for `foo()`.

I looked at the idea with `LD_PRELOAD` which I think is not the solution for this case since it only changes the shared library loading order, not really override the function `foo()` in `libX.so`, i.e `bar()` will still call the `foo()` with the version implemented by the shared library itself.

Assume we can't change nor recompile the source code from the shared library, is that possible? Thanks in advance! Any help is appreciated!

Comment: [Dynamic linker tricks: Using LD_PRELOAD to cheat, inject features and investigate programs](https://rafalcieslak.wordpress.com/2013/04/02/dynamic-linker-tricks-using-ld_preload-to-cheat-inject-features-and-investigate-programs/) -  It's a bit aged, but may provide some hints.

Comment: @TedLyngmo thanks for the link. I think the example about the rand() is different with my example above, rand() is called in the program so that `LD_PRELOAD` can make the custom implementation in the shared library be seen first. My issue is that the program should still call the interface in the original shared library, inside that interface, it calls rand() with the custom behavior we want. Not we call rand() directly.

Comment: Is it for your own amusement or for mocking or hacking? If you paint a  picture of what you'd like to get out of it, it may get the people who knows about how to do it out.

Comment: It's a real case. Two different systems use the same logic in the shared library, but they are running on different conditions. Thus for system A we would like it to run `foo()` as it is, but for system B we would like different behaviors on `foo()`. If we can touch the source code, then we can generate different version of `foo()` for system B to use, but based on the assumption, it's not.

Comment: Are they ABI compatible? You can for sure "_change the behavior of a global function that is inside (not isolated from) one shared library but not directly invoked by the program_" - I think that's called mocking. I'm not a big fan :-)

Comment: That's platform-dependent. In Linux, if more than one module (module: shared object or main executable) contains the same (non static) symbol ('bar'), then the one loaded first will be used by all modules. Note: usually the main executable is being loaded first, except for shared objects loaded by LD_PRELOAD.

Comment: "Thus for system A we would like it to run foo() as it is, but for system B we would like different behaviors on foo()" is this system totally in the third party library or just calling the same api of third party library?

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond I did an experimental with the above example in clang10, the LD_PRELOAD works fine. However, When I apply this to my shared library, it's not "the one loaded first will be used by all modules". I checked the symbol through `nm` and `readelf` for both shared libraries, they are exactly the same on that function. Do you know what the possible reasons will cause this?

Comment: @LouisGo they are calling the same api of the thrid party library

Comment: @goldenretriever Do you have source code of System A and B? If yes, using design pattern is better than overriding third party library behavior. Even system A and B are the same class, you may alter its behavior by arguments. Unless you can't alter these system.

Comment: @LouisGo I have the source but I don't think design pattern can solve our requirement since both System A and B needs to call the same API from that shared library, .i.e. both systems will dynamically link with the .so file, but for B, we want the `foo()` function in the shared library behaves differently.

Comment: I misunderstood your question, sorry. It seems library only exposing `bar` but need to alter `foo`'s behavior..

Comment: @OP It would  be the right time to create a [mcve]

Comment: Another example: some program (like mydumper) depends on 3rd party library (like glib) implementation of function (like g_key_file_parse_line()) which cannot do all the functionality needed. This function is a part of parser from that 3rd party library and not called directly from the program. Reimplementing parser in the program is a long story and maybe not worth it. Reporting a bug to 3rd party library and waiting until it propagates into distributed binaries is a story even longer (if not neverending). If I want the patch right now I'd prefer to just reimplement the wrong function.

Comment: Oh, it is static. The things are even worse...